# How to find the difference in next highest value in sequence in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

need some help. I'm trying to find the difference in the next highest value in a range in the sequence it appears. something like this:

GIVEN DATA:

> No.  Rate
>   1   59%
>   2   59%
>   3   59%
>   4   60%
>   5   60%
>   6   60%
>   7   60%
>   8   61%
>   9   61%

RESULT TO DERIVE:

Rank-Rate-How many levels needed

> 1-59%-N/A
>   2-60%-3

The Rate is to be ranked from lowest to highest in the given data list which in this case 1st is 59% followed by 60%. The number of levels needed where answer = 3 is the difference between 1st 59% to the 1st 60% that appears base on sequence. The problem now is there are many 60% that appears.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify the question a bit? Where does answer = 3 come from? There are 4 instances of 60% and the difference between 59% & 60% is 1...

Answer (score -1):

Excel has a "countif" function that you can provide different criteria and it will give you the number of values in a given range that meet that criteria.  In your case, suppose all the values are in column A.  You can put the following formulae in column B:

```
=Countif(A:A, "<"&A1) <-- and copy this down for the range of values.
```

I think that will do what you want.

Comment: No, it will return "0".  The question didn't specifically say they needed "N/A" as a result for the lowest value.  If that's what they have to have, they can add an "If" statement to change the output to "N/A" in that special case.

Comment: Are we trying to get a count or a DIFFERENCE?

Comment: @pnuts - agreed. This answer may be a step along the way, but from the question, this is not what littlenova is looking for. Let's wait for some additional guidance & try to help Big_Al_Tx revise his answer so that he can build his rep...